# Identify this sanskrit mantra?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit

[image]

Could anyone please help me identify/translate this sanskrit mantra? I am grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: From a Tibetan textile curator/dealer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is Om Namoh Durgeh in Devanagari script while considering the two dots are visarga. It is a mantra dedicated to Goddess Durga.

Below is IAST transliteration.

> oṃ namoḥ durgeḥ

It means salutations to Durga.

But some people put ':' after a word to indicate a long sound. If that is the case, it is

> Oṃ namo durge

The second pronunciation is right.

For the correct mantra containing Om, it should be Om Durgayai namaha

> Oṃ durgāyai namaḥ

Comment: Sarvabhouma, thank you for the detailed reply. I want you to know it has helped me along my journey.

Comment: @TectonicTerra You are welcome. If you have found this answer helpful, you can upvote and accept it by clicking the tick beside the answer. Keep participating on the site. All the best!